# What kind of edge detection use paint.net?

Tags: edge-detection

What kind of edge detection is used Paint.NET program? It allows me to choose the angle of the edge not like the one used by opencv ([Canny](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#Canny)).

Here an example:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The edges doesn't have single pixel width, so it's probably not canny (no non-maxima supression). Could be a simple high-pass filter, whose pass-band is masked out in the Fourier domain in specific angles.

Comment: Opencv can do that?